# Prevent object owned by shared_ptr from being deleted while member function executes

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have two classes. For illustrative purposes, I'm using the idea of a menu and menu items

```
class Menu {
 public:
  ...
  RemoveItem(Item* item) {
    // Remove appropriate item from menu_items vector
  };

 private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> menu_items;
}

class Item {
 public:
  Item(Menu* owner) : menu{owner} {}

  ~Item() { RemoveThisMenuItem() }

  void RemoveThisMenuItem() {
    for (const auto& ingredient : ingredients) {
      ingredient.SetNecessary(false);
    }
    menu.RemoveItem(this);
  }
  ...

 private:
  Menu* menu;
  std::vector<Ingredients*> ingredients;
  ...
}
```

Essentially, I have a class `Item` that is owned by a class `Menu` (and possibly referenced elsewhere with `shared_ptr`s). Now, I want to remove an Item. When Item is deleted, it needs to perform some other functions first (like marking all of the ingredients unnecessary) and then remove it from the `Menu`.

The way things are implemented now, there's a strange loop when we want to remove the item, since calling `Item::RemoveThisMenuItem()` calls a function in `Menu` that removes the smart pointer to the `Item`, which calls the destructor `~Item()`, which then calls `Item::RemoveThisMenuItem()`. What's the best way to get around this?

Comment: If `Item::~Item` is executing, then the item must have already been removed from the menu. Otherwise there would still be a `shared_ptr<Item>` for it and it would not have been destroyed yet. If you are destroying an `Item` which there is still a `shared_ptr<Item>` to it you have a design error elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Please clarify your question with a complete example. It's unclear how you can be trying to remove something from the vector while it is being destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Make another copy of the `shared_ptr` which owns the item, and will destroy it when it goes out of scope.

i.e. instead of doing:

```
menu_items[n]->RemoveThisMenuItem();
```

do:

```
{
  auto owner = menu_items[n];
  owner->RemoveThisMenuItem();
}
```

Now when `RemoveThisMenuItem()` erases the element from the vector it isn't the last object that shares ownership of the `Item`, and so it won't be destroyed until `owner` goes out of scope.

Comment: `RemoveThisMenuItem` is being called from the context of the destructor. The destructor is already running. If there was a `std::shared_ptr` to copy, the destructor would not be running in the first place.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't see that. Yes, something is wrong with the design then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change method `void RemoveItem(Item* item)` to `std::shared_ptr<Item> RemoveItem(Item* item)` and implement it in a way that it moves/copies the respective item-shared_ptr out of the vector and returns it; if the item has already been removed, return an empty shared ptr to avoid endless recursion. This way, you prevent `RemoveItem` to ocassionally delete the Item-object (in case the last shared_ptr of it was destroyed) and delegate the topic to the caller of RemoveItem. The caller can then decide if to keep such a shared_pointer (and thereby the corresponding object) alive or not.

For example:

```
void RemoveThisMenuItem() {
   for (const auto& ingredient : ingredients) {
      ingredient.SetNecessary(false);
   }
   auto ptr = menu.RemoveItem(this);
   // at that point, "this" will have not been destroyed;
   // when the method is left, however, ptr will be destroyed and the destructor will be called; 
}
```